# InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

Tags: java, singleton, ejb, interrupted-exception

I am delaying my application for sometime and sometimes I receive the following Exception:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
```

I have been on this Exception for over one week and still no solution found. I have read a lot of forums and then mention that I need to either do the following:

- throw a RuntimeException
- Thread.currentThread().interrupt() by restoring the status of the Thread

The problem is that this Exception only occurs after the following is executed in Glassfish:

```
[#|2014-05-16T17:24:15.881+0100|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=13;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: admin-thread-pool-4848(2).|#]
```

I only have one Thread in the program and the program needs to continue to execute. Below is the code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Listener {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1000));
                // there are other codes that insert to the database and get information back from the database
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interuppted status
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get from the stacktrace:

```
[#|2014-05-16T17:24:15.881+0100|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=13;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: admin-thread-pool-4848(2).|#]

[#|2014-05-16T17:24:15.881+0100|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at com.screening.listener.Listener.init(Listener.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:113)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:138)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:719)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:451)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:216)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:177)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:155)
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:177)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

|#]

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless this thread is interrupted, it will continue to sleep as its in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

This looks bad to me. You have an infinite loop in a @PostConstruct. To me, this says your container will never be able to startup since Listener never finishes it's construction phase.

Are you sure you don't want to do this work (the infinite loop) on a separate thread? Perhaps you want to use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

eg:

```
@Inject ScheduledExecutorService executor;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doSomeStuffInTheDatabase();
        }
    };
    long delaySeconds = 1;
    long periodSeconds = 1;
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, delaySeconds, periodSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: How would you change the code to do exactly what I want to do? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Will this mean that the container will start up in the Listener and it finsihes construction phase and continue to check the database constantly?

Comment: Why don't you write a test case and find out for yourself?

Comment: You'll need to `sleep()` on the main thread to stop the test from terminating before the schedule gets a chance to run.

Comment: So do you mean Thread.sleep(1000) before the Runnable runnable = new Runnable()? Could you please modify your code to show this?

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you. If you are writing a test case... add a sleep() after the call to scheduleAtFixedRate(...)